# How to Change language of gedit in WSL

Tags: windows-10, gedit, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed WSL on windows 10. After that using VcXsrv, I can launch `gedit` editor from the installed WSL. Moreover, I have tried to install Arabic and Persian language using [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1451241), and it was successful.

Anyhow, the question is how can I write in Persian in a launched `gedit` in WSL?
I should have mentioned that changing the language of windows to Persian does not help me to write Persian on `gedit` anymore.

[image]

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `locale`? Thanks.

Comment: **To close voters:** WSL is not generally off topic. While graphical applications in that environment are problematic, locale settings should work in a similar fashion than in any native Ubuntu installation.

Comment: **To close voters:** This is definitely an on-topic question about ***Ubuntu Bash on Windows*** aka WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) which has it's own tag here in **Ask Ubuntu**.

Answer (score 1):

From [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1108090/how-do-i-change-the-language-of-the-linux-subsystem-in-windows-10-wsl):

The Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) installation should automatically set the Ubuntu locale to match the locale of your Windows install. You can change the Ubuntu locale manually using the shell.

```
sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF8
```

Replace "en_US.UTF8" with your desired language. If you have any problems visit the link for extra steps.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned I want Persian language. Hence, I have tried `LANG=fa.UTF8` but it does not work. Getting this error: `*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LANG=fa.UTF8`.

Comment: I've never changed the language myself. I suggest posting your error message in the comments of the SuperUser link above.

Comment: I did this. It does not work. Again, the language in gedit is in English.